# Is there a non-binary format for an Outlook email message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, file-format

*I want to create an e-mail file on a web server that **will open in Microsoft Outlook***.  It appears the two formats that would come in handy are the .MSG format and .OFT format.

However, both appear to be GZIP'ed formats with a bunch of streams.  This would be tough to generate on a web server.

Is there an XML or text based format I can use to encode a simple email?

If not, is there a free .NET library that can generate an email message on the fly?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) could come handy for you?

Comment: @Marco Does Redemption work in a "headless" mode? (MAPI but no Outlook).

Comment: What do you mean by "email file", like a .pst?

Comment: Looks like a commercial library, I've found a few of those..

Comment: @pst: I'm not sure, but I think it can't... check website docs and helps... sorry...

Comment: I mean a single email message.  Such as a .MSG file (If you double cilck on it, it just opens up in Outlook) or a .OFT file (an Outlook template for an email you can then edit and send to someone)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use OpenMCDF to build a file on the fly.  This is working pretty well, and it's a decent (and free) framework for working with compact binary files.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for showing us this great tool I've never heard about!! My question is: to write a .msg file you need to know which streams add and how, so where did you learn this? Did you find some doc? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just use [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) and write to the file system:

```
<system.net>  
   <mailSettings>  
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">  
         <specifiedPickupDirectory 
             pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\yourdirectory"/>  
      </smtp>  
   </mailSettings>  
</system.net>
```

Comment: These files are open-able by Outlook?

Comment: It's the first time I see something about this: you're great!!! But, sorry, how can you save message on hdd? Creating a new smtp message and sending it?

Comment: It looks like the only way to do it is to use an SmtpClient classs, then save the file to the disk.  I'd then have to immediately re-open the file and write it out to the Response object.  I guess that would work, too bad the MailMessage class doesn't have a way to access the .eml data as a byte array or something.

Comment: Yes, just use the API as if you are sending it, it will use the SMTP setting to write to disk instead.

Comment: This doesn't work anyway.  It dumps out a .EML file (which is plain text).  This file format doesn't open in Outlook, it tries to load Outlook Express.  I think I need a .MSG file.